# Data table warning : table id=datatable- request unknown parameter

Tags: datatables

my problem is, im attached the image, you can understand my problem, im try to fix it, more than 2 hours, i cant fix it, please help me to fix my problem.this is a advance search part of my project.,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENPrA.jpg)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="modal fade" id="mpSrch" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width: 95%">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header btn-primary btn-sm" style="height: 40px;">
                                <button style="margin-top: -10px;" type="button" class="close btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                <h6 style="margin-top: -5px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>Good Recieve Note</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="modal-content" style="margin-left: 27px;width: 1250px;padding: 2px;">
                                            <table id="datatable" class="datatableDisplay" font-size:"11pt">
                                                <thead>


                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Id</th>
                                                           <th style="width:150px;">GRN No</th>
                                                         <th style="width:150px;">GRN Date</th>

                                                         <th style="width:150px;">Company Name</th> 
                                                         <th style="width:150px;">Purchase Order No</th>
                                                          <th style="width:150px;">Confirm Status</th>
                                                            <th>Action</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tfoot>
                                                    <div id="eee">
                                                        <tr>

                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th> 
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>

                                                        </tr>
                                                    </div>
                                                </tfoot>
                                            </table>
                                            <div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
```

---

```
  $(document).on('click', '.selectid', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#hfRowItem1').val(parseInt($(this).parents('tr').children('td').eq(0).html()));
     $('#btnFakeRowClick').trigger('click');
 });


 $(function Pageload() {
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function() {

         $(document).ready(function() {
             var dataTableInstance = $('#datatable').DataTable({
                 "iDisplayLength": 5,
                 "bStateSave": false,
                 "oLanguage": {
                     "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option></select> entries'
                 },
                 "bJQueryUI": true,
                 "bAutoWidth": false,
                 columns: [{
                         'data': 'GRNId',
                         className: 'hide_column'
                     }, {
                         'data': 'GRNNo'
                     },

                     {
                         'data': 'GRNDate',
                         'render': function(jsonDate) {
                             var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                             var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                             return ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + month).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                         }
                     },

                     {
                         'data': 'CompanyName'
                     }, {
                         'data': 'PurchaseOrderNo'
                     }, {
                         'data': 'ConfirmStatus'
                     }, {
                         'data': null,
                         className: "center",
                         defaultContent: '<a href="" class="selectid">Select</a>',
                         'width': '5%'
                     }
                 ],
                 bServerSide: true,
                 sAjaxSource: 'GenericHandlers/GoodReceiveNoteDataHandler.ashx'
             });

             $('#datatable tfoot th').each(function() {
                 if ($(this).index() != 0 && $(this).index() != 9) {
                     $(this).html('<input type="text" class="dtSrchCol" placeholder="Search">');
                     if ($(this).index() == 2) {
                         $(this).find('input').addClass('datetimepicker');
                     }
                 }
             });

             dataTableInstance.columns().every(function() {
                 var datatableColumn = this;

                 $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function() {
                     datatableColumn.search(this.value).draw();
                 });
             });
         });
     });
 });
 $(document).ready(Pageload);
```

Comment: pleses show entire html here

Comment: "#datatable" i'm not able to see this id into your  html code?

Comment: @DipakThoke       sir im updated my question

Comment: add  one more  <th></th> in the tfoot tag it might help you.